# GL_QUADS draws a concave pentagon instead of recangle

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glut

I'm using this code to generate the rectangle

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(0,0,0);
glVertex2f(-0.9,-0.9);
glVertex2f(-0.9,+0.9);
glVertex2f(+0.9,-0.9);
glVertex2f(+0.9,+0.9);
glEnd();
```

[Draws this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2uHv.png)

My window is setup with this code:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutCreateWindow("Atari Breakout!");
glClearColor(0,1,0,1);
glOrtho(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f,+1.0f,1,1);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(display);

glutMainLoop();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of your vertices are like the letter `N` which flips the winding around mid primitive. You have to submit the vertices in a consistent winding order.